# ValueError: certfile "/home/ubuntu/ssl/cert.pem" does not exist on local mac

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook

I recently upgraded my personal machine to Mac OS Monterey and now I get this error when I try to open a jupyter notebook with `python -m jupyter notebook`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/travisbarton/opt/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/travisbarton/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 267, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/travisbarton/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 663, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "</Users/travisbarton/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/decorator.py:decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/Users/travisbarton/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/travisbarton/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1679, in initialize
    self.init_webapp()
  File "/Users/travisbarton/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1437, in init_webapp
    max_buffer_size=self.max_buffer_size)
  File "/Users/travisbarton/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/util.py", line 286, in __new__
    instance.initialize(*args, **init_kwargs)
  File "/Users/travisbarton/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/httpserver.py", line 191, in initialize
    read_chunk_size=chunk_size,
  File "/Users/travisbarton/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 134, in __init__
    'certfile "%s" does not exist' % self.ssl_options["certfile"]
ValueError: certfile "/home/ubuntu/ssl/cert.pem" does not exist
```

This is new and I've been able to use notebooks here before. Any ideas why?

Comment: do you have an environmental variable `SSL_CERT_FILE` defined? Type `env` and look or type `env | grep CERT`.

Comment: `env | grep CERT` comes up empty, I don't see it manually looking either

Comment: Then perhaps you have a config field of `c.NotebookApp.certfile` with that `/home/ubuntu/ssl/cert.pem` file as the value causing the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with Anaconda.

Try to install it again with:

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab
```

Comment: I tried this no luck, then I uninstalled jupyter and then did this again, no luck still unfortunately

Comment: OK. Create virtual environment and install Jupyter in the virtual environment. That should fix it

Comment: I've done that with anaconda with no luck. My base and my different virtual environments arent working. steps: `conda create --name testenv` `conda activate testenv` `conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab` `python -m jupyter notebook` same error